# TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script I hacked together to run once a day but at the end of every day I get an email from Google saying that the script failed to run 1440 times. The script works fine, but I've no idea how to just end the script if the time is not 17:00

```
function stockBot() {
var date = new Date();  
var day = date.getDay();
var hrs = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
if ((hrs >= 17) && (hrs <= 17) && (min >= 0) && (min <= 0 ))

// select the range from the Summary sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stock-Bot-Order");

// MAGHERAFELT List 
var range = sheet.getRange(3,4,1,1).getValues();
var user = "Magherafelt";
// loop over range and send communication if "Yes" option chosen
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
if (range[i][0] != "") {
      // post message to slack
      sendToSlack(range[i],user);
      break;
};
}

// function to send message to Slack
function sendToSlack(item,user) {

// custom slack webhook
var url = "private";

var payload = {
"channel": "#stock-requests",
"icon_emoji": ":package:",
"link_names": 1,
"username" : user+" Stock Order",
"text": item[0]
};

var options = {
"method": "post",
"contentType": "application/json",
"payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};

return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between the title and the post body here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical statement for comparing time is looking like the source of error here *(on line 6)*. Try changing to the following:

```
if ((hrs == 17) && (min == 18)){
  // continue your code

  // alternatively, you can terminate if the above statement is not true
```